# What are the prerequisites for Eclipse 64 bit?

Tags: eclipse

What are the prerequisites for Eclipse 64 bit? 
Do I have to download eclipse 64 bit for jdk 1.6 64 bit or 32 bit jdk will suffice to work with 64 bit DLLs? I have configured 32 bit Eclipse to have 64 bit JDK. But when I run my test suite then I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemory error`

Comment: Anand: if you found one of the answers worked, you're supposed to click the checkmark by it. That tells other SO users that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed Eclipse 64-bit, I had to install 64-bit JDK. I'm not 100% sure if it is an absolute requirement, but it seems to be the best way.

Plus the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Java can coexist on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mix the 64-bit eclipse with a 32-bit JDK or vice versa.  Stick with 64-bit or 32-bit for both.  Of course as Almo says, you can have both installed and tell eclipse to use the correct jvm using the eclipse.ini file.